# 310 Redirect loop error in chrome due to Machii Redirect event

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, mach-ii

I am getting a 310: Too many redirects error in Chrome when I run my website. However this is not the case for IE or Firefox.

I am using Mach-ii framework and this is the case where I am using redirect in an event-handler.

e.g:

```
<event-handler event="A">
    <announce event="B">
    <announce event="C">
</event-handler>

<event-handler event="C">
    <redirect event="D">
</event-handler>

<event-handler event="D">
    <view-page name="foo">
</event-handler>
```

So, if I get to this page, it renders perfectly. But if I hit browser back and then next button again, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common solutions to this kind of error from Chrome could be

- Delete all the site's cookies and restart your browser.
- Synchronize your computers time. In the date and time settings for your computer, sync it to a time server.

I've also heard of different update channels having the issue and others not. As in the Beta channel for Chrome would not have this issue, but the Stable version does have the issue. I've heard of things like plugins (chrome scripts) being a problem. I suppose as a last solution remove Chrome completely and install it from fresh.

I personally dont think its a Mach-ii or Coldfusion issue. Hope you come right.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for this tip. I have already tried all of the above steps along with clearing cache in Mach-ii. I created separate listeners too and tried using <cflocation>, but it's still the same.

Comment: Best advice would be to test this with someone else's install of Chrome. If the problem persists, then submit a bug report to Chrome.